# \dot not available on XeLaTeX with package eulervm

Tags: fonts, libertine, eulervm

When compiling this document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[biolinum]{libertine}
\usepackage[euler-digits,small]{eulervm}

\begin{document}

\[
U=-\dot\Phi=-\frac d{dx}\int_A B\;dA
\]

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 U=-\dot
            \Phi=-\frac d{dx}\int_A B\;dA
```

Why is `\dot` undefined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to load `eulervm` before `libertine`

```
\usepackage[euler-digits,small]{eulervm}
\usepackage[biolinum]{libertine}
```

I had to change `libertine` to `libertineotf`, it seems you have an outdated distribution.

From TeX Live 2016 (precisely since `fontspec` switched to the TU encoding), the code needs to be

```
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[euler-digits,small]{eulervm}
\usepackage[biolinum]{libertine}
```

which will keep `eulervm` happy.

Comment: Hm... On my machine, there is no package called `libertineotf`. What could it be?

Comment: @FUZxxl You have an outdated distribution. :)

Comment: That is strange. I have texlive 2009 installed.

Comment: @FUZxxl TeX Live 2009 *is* outdated. The current TeX Live is 2011, but Debian (Ubuntu) systems don't carry it. :(

Comment: Hm... So the only thing I can do is wating or using a PPA?

Comment: You can install TeX Live 2011: http://tug.org/texlive

Comment: @egreg This solution does not seem to work with, for example, `eulervm` and `amsmath`.  Loading `eulervm` first causes major problem.  (Maybe related to [Package clash fontspec eulervm amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272491/package-clash-fontspec-eulervm-amsmath). Shall I ask a new, almost identical question for that case?

Comment: @mforbes Thanks for reporting; I just tried and the code worked up to TeX Live 2015; with TL 2016 it fails, apparently for changes in `fontspec`.

Comment: @mforbes Added a workaround