# Incorrect digits font with newtxmath and Luatex/Xetex (since Texlive 2015)

Tags: fonts, luatex, newtxmath

I used to use Luatex and a combination of the packages *fontspec* and *newtxmath* to have everything set in Libertine. However, it does not work anymore since Texlive 2015: it compiles be the digits in math-mode are set in Computer modern and not Libertine.

Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
123 $123$ --- \emph{a} $a$
\end{document}
```

It used to work with both LuaTex and Xelatex, but now it works with none. With Xelatex, I can solve the problem with *mathspec*, by specifying explicitly the font for the digits, but for Luatex, I have no fix. The log reveals nothing (no warning, no errors).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

The same workaround as for [package clash fontspec eulervm amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272491/package-clash-fontspec-eulervm-amsmath) applies, both for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
123 $123$ --- \emph{a} $a$
\end{document}
```

Loading `fontenc` is completely useless.

[image]

Comment: Nice ! (I put *fontenc* because newtxmath's doc says so... But indeed, it is useless.)

Comment: @Lierre - The packages `inputenc` and `fontenc` should not be loaded under LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.