# Fails to compile with XeLaTeX in TL2015 when including `newtxmath`

Tags: xetex, texlive, newtxmath

All my LaTeX documents stopped compiling with XeLaTeX from TeX Live 2015 sometime in the last two months.  It was working before.  Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

% \DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Trying to compile like this: `xelatex -interaction nonstopmode bug`, gives me the following error:

```
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex)
\tx@Isdigit=\count137
)
! Incomplete \iftrue; all text was ignored after line 128.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.5 

The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

)
! Incomplete \iftrue; all text was ignored after line 128.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> bug

The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Emergency stop.
<*> bug

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

What is going wrong?  I have tried the suggestion in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279466/4416) with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in `newtxmath`. If contains in line 130 (and line 135) in an `\else`-branch

```
\ifx\iflibertine@otf\undefined
```

and this leads to an incomplete `if` if the branch is not executed.

A similar problem can be demonstrated with this example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\newif\ifblab
\iftrue
abc
\else
  \ifx
    \ifblab\undefined
    abc
  \fi
\fi

\end{document}
```

TeX is trying to find the end of the `\else` part to throw it away and due to the `\ifblab` one `\fi` is missing.

Comment: Thanks for digging through the source. I'm guessing there is no workaround? How can I report this bug? `texdoc newtx` didn't tell me much.

Comment: @suvayu  The mail address is in the sty.