# Fontspec isn't changing digits in math mode

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, mathspec

I had been using the following in my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,zswash,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Rare}]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
This is a 123 test $123$.
\end{document}
```

until I noticed that this produced the following ugly result with the wrong digits font:[image: Wrong digits!]
I have come up with a temporary solution using `mathspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,zswash,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts(Digits,Latin)[Ligatures={TeX,Rare}]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
This is a 123 test $123$.
\end{document}
```

and this indeed fixes the problem:
[image: Correct digits]
The issue is that `mathspec` requires me to use XeTeX, which is incompatible with my current workflow—I *need* to use LuaTex. Is there a way to fix this issue without invoking `mathspec`?

Comment: fontspec doesn't change the math setup at all, you could use unicode-math rather than mathspec, but more directly I think the question is the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279463/incorrect-digits-font-with-newtxmath-and-luatex-xetex-since-texlive-2015

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Carlisle I think I understand what you're saying. Your suggestion to use unicode-math differs from the post you linked though - any reason to choose either method?

Comment: unicode-math will (in general) change all the math setup to use opentype math fonts instead of the classic tex math layout, that was more of a general comment on how to affect math in unicode engines.  the second one was a result of specifically searching this site for a duplicate answer, it just specifically addresses the digits and operator fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I briefly looked at unicode-math's documentation and I couldn't understand what the purpose of package was. The solution in the linked question is easy enough to understand - but could you point me to something that explains what unicode-math is to someone unfamiliar with the landscape? I'd like to evaluate which solution is more appropriate in my use case.

Comment: unicode-math is essentially the math support for fontspec (by the same author) it sets up luatex or xetex to use math specific opentype fonts with an opentype MATH table.

Comment: This was fixed in a newer version of `fontspec`, see https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/357

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With unicode-math you can use the TeX Gyre Termes Math font. TeX Gyre Termes is a times clone and so will fit to your text font:

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Rare}]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
This is a 123 test $123$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

I tested your first example. In texlive 2019 there is no problem, the output is as wanted:

[image]

In texlive 2017 I get like you the "wrong" font, there it helps to use

```
 \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative, but it does not solve my problem; I am partial to `mtpro2`.

Comment: Then why do you complain about the math digits it uses?

Comment: `mtpro2` uses the already set math font to define the digits. For some reason it thinks the font is still computer modern (although according to the above discussion this is because `fontspec` does not change math fonts at all)

Comment: no the digits are from mt2mit.pfb, you only need to look in the log.

Comment: Actually I just realized that your mt2pro output is different to mine. Can you show the log-file?

Comment: Sure. [Here](https://pastebin.com/K91rd500) it is.

Comment: well your system is much older than mine. And yes, it uses cmr10 and not mt2mit as does mine.

Comment: I added an edit for a work-around in tl17.

Comment: This was fixed in a newer version of `fontspec`, along with 4 other math packages which will automatically invoke the `no-math` option (back in Feb.), see https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/357